# How to configure firewall on Centos 7 for KVM Routed Bridge

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, kvm, bridge

I want to set up multiple virtual machines to run webserver, postfix, etc.

I have a few public IP-Adresses from my ISP. My host system is running Centos 7 and my virtual machines are running Debian Wheezy. Since my hoster restrict access to the switch based on MAC Address, I cannot use a "full" bridge.

Instead I configured a routed bridge ([see http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Proxmox_VE](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Proxmox_VE#Netzwerkkonfiguration_Hostsystem_KVM.2FRouted))

I have successfully set up both machines, but the vm cannot connect to the internet if my firewall on my host machine is active. If my firewall is active I can ping machines on the internet from my vm, but nothing else.

How can I configure my firewall under Centos 7 to give the VMs on br0 acces to internet?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

**Network Config Host Machine**

Host-Machine: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0

```
 BOOTPROTO=none
 DEVICE=enp2s0
 ONBOOT=yes
 IPADDR=A.A.A.42
 NETMASK=255.255.255.255
 SCOPE="peer A.A.A.1"
```

Host-Machine: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-enp2s0

```
 ADDRESS0=0.0.0.0
 NETMASK0=0.0.0.0
 GATEWAY0=A.A.A.1
```

Host-Machine: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0

```
 DEVICE=br0
 TYPE="Bridge"
 ONBOOT=yes
 BOOTPROTO=none
 IPADDR=A.A.A.42
 NETMASK=255.255.255.255
 STP=off
 DELAY=0
```

Host Machine: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-br0

```
 ADDRESS0=B.B.B.160
 NETMASK0=255.255.255.255
```

**Network Config Virtual machine**

Virtual machine: /etc/network/interfaces

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
 allow-hotplug eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
         address B.B.B.160
         netmask 255.255.255.255
         pointopoint A.A.A.42
         gateway A.A.A.42
```

**Firewall settings Host machine**
firewall-cmd --list-all

```
public (default, active)
  interfaces: br0 enp2s0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6):

To accomplish, you have two options.

**Option1**:(from a security perspective this method is recommended)

*Disable netfilter on the configured bridge*

# vi /etc/sysctl.conf

> net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
>
> net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
>
> net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0

Check the values before/after.

# sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

**Option2:**

*Add direct firewall rule*

> firewall-cmd --direct --add-chain ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT

Comment: Note, the command should use `--add-rule` and not `--add-chain`: `firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT`

Comment: This is described here: https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Net.bridge.bridge-nf-call_and_sysctl.conf and I spent two weeks debugging strange guest vm behaviour until I found the necessary configuration hints. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS 8 (and probably CentOS 7) with firewalld, there's a much easier way to get all routed bridged KVM virtual machines full unrestricted internet access without dealing with firewall rules.

By default, all interfaces are bound to the public firewall zone.
But there are multiple zones, ie `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` of which one is called `trusted`, which is an unfiltered firewall zone that accepts all packets by default.
So you can just bind the bridge interface to that zone.

```
firewall-cmd --remove-interface br0 --zone=public --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-interface br0 --zone=trusted --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can confirm that that this solution works for me (after spending two days mucking around with bridge and NetworkManager settings).

Comment: Out if curiosity, what system can you confirm this solution works on ?

Comment: I tested on CentOS 8.  The problem (at least for me) was googling for bridge and kvm yielded the same results.  The head-bonking moment was when I read your answer and it dawned on me that `firewalld` is much more flexible than traditional iptables (what I was used to).   Thanks for the recommendation.